# For loop performance much slower when using int64 instead of int32

Tags: performance, for-loop, go, int

I am trying to figure out the best practices regarding performance.
I have noticed that specifying integer types for a for-loop could effect the performance drastically (x2 times in my case).

My question is, is it supposed to be that using the int64 would be much slower than using int32 or I am missing something in my code?

The code I am using:

**a.go**

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
    "runtime"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    start := time.Now()
    var x1 int // later change all int to int32 or int64 

    for i := int(0); i <= int(1000000000); i++  {
        x1 = x1 + i
    }
        t := time.Now()
        elapsed := t.Sub(start)

    fmt.Println(x1)
    fmt.Println(elapsed)
    fmt.Println(runtime.Compiler, runtime.GOARCH, runtime.GOOS)
    fmt.Println(strconv.IntSize)
}
```

**Output using int32 for x1**

```sh
C:\...>go build a.go
C:\...>a

-243309312
238.3333ms
gc amd64 windows
64
```

**Output using int64 for x1**

```sh
C:\...>go build a.go
C:\...>a

500000000500000000
467.7835ms
gc amd64 windows
64
```

**Update**

I tried @Giulio Micheloni suggestion and got more accurate benchmark.

```
goos: windows
goarch: amd64
BenchmarkInt64-12       1000000000           0.234 ns/op           0 B/op          0 allocs/op
PASS
ok      _/c_/.../.../Desktop    0.402s
Success: Benchmarks passed.

goos: windows
goarch: amd64
BenchmarkInt32-12       1000000000           0.231 ns/op           0 B/op          0 allocs/op
PASS
ok      _/c_/.../.../Desktop    0.403s
Success: Benchmarks passed.
```

Comment: Does this happen consistently?

Comment: @GiulioMicheloni yes

Comment: I would run a benchmark like this (https://play.golang.org/p/OgsrVVWJeuq) and make sure that the for-loop's number of iterations is not in the equation. Can you let us know the results of above benchmarks? I ran those in my machine and got similar results for both integer sizes:
Int32-16  0.44ns ± 0%
Int64-16  0.45ns ± 1%

Comment: @GiulioMicheloni after your comment and peterSO's post I see what the problem was. Now, I can't help but to ask the annoying question; why is the go code twice slower than it's Java equivalent (rhetorical question).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Meaningless microbenchmarks produce meaningless results.

---

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Numeric types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Numeric_types)
>
> ```
> int32   set of all signed 32-bit integers 
>         (-2147483648 to 2147483647)
> int64   set of all signed 64-bit integers 
>         (-9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807)
> ```
>
> [Arithmetic operators](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Arithmetic_operators)
>
> Integer overflow
>
> For signed integers, the operations +, -, *, /, and << may legally
>   overflow and the resulting value exists and is deterministically
>   defined by the signed integer representation, the operation, and its
>   operands. Overflow does not cause a run-time panic.

---

Overflow!

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
    "runtime"
    "strconv"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    start := time.Now()
    var x1 int32 // later change all int to int32 or int64

    for i := int32(0); i <= int32(1000000000); i++ {

        if int64(x1)+int64(i) > math.MaxInt32 {
            fmt.Println("Overflow:", x1, "+", i, "=", x1+i)
            break
        }

        x1 = x1 + i
    }
    t := time.Now()
    elapsed := t.Sub(start)

    fmt.Println(x1)
    fmt.Println(elapsed)
    fmt.Println(runtime.Compiler, runtime.GOARCH, runtime.GOOS)
    fmt.Println(strconv.IntSize)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/bdhB4ABf7jY

Output:

```
Overflow: 2147450880 + 65536 = -2147450880
gc amd64 linux
64
```

Comment: @Kingindanord, when doing microbenchmarks, please 1) do not rely on wall-clock timers, use the benchmarking abilities of the stock package [`testing`](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#hdr-Benchmarks); 2) be sure to also use the [`benchcmp`](https://golang.org/x/tools/cmd/benchcmp) package to compare the results of different benchmark runs; 3) make sure to not measure any setup and teardown code of your benchmark; 4) read up on benchmarking in Go, a lot.